# Why do I get very slow internet wired connexion on my Pi4 while my desktop PC is doing fine?

Tags: networking, pi-4, ethernet, internet

### Issue

I'm hardly getting 100--140Mbps on my Pi4 (model B rev. 1.4 at 8GB ram) through wired ethernet cat 8 connection to a 2.5Gb port on my router.
Plus, the upload speed is higher, reaching 350Mbps (which is wierd!)

By comparison, using the same wire and same i/o port on my router to hook up my desktop PC to the internet, I get 1GBps...

I've been reading the whole evening a certain variety of posts which expose similar situations but I couldn't manage to find the answer: Pi4 is supposed to be equipped with true 1Gb Ethernet, isn't it??

I've read about the Pi3B+ limitations due to USB bridge and also about possible interference with Bluetooth and Wi-Fi, but disabling those didn't work.

FYI the context is really simple: I'm just trying to use the Pi as a regular computer for simple online tasks such as browsing internet and watching Netflix...

---

### Edit

1. I figured I could test my second RPi4 (same model, 4GB ram), but the results are very low too though they are not exactly the same : 75 Mbps download and 150 Mbps upload.
2. There is nothing attached to the USB ports beside keyboard and mouse, but the first RPi4 has  joy-it armour on it (the big heat sync with two fans connected to the 5v pins)

Comment: Lots of people come to this site and whinge about "slow" this, that and the other. Unfortunately they fail to substantiate their claims, provide no evidence or details of their environment. Consequently they are ignored or invite speculation, which is rarely useful.

Comment: I think your perhaps confusing the 1Gigabit full duplex in ideal conditions with actual real life speeds..

20MB's (160Mbps) on a 1GB network is a pretty average speed depending on the state of the cables and the con-current traffic on them.  

Also the RPI4 is the CPU is the ultimate bottleneck for IO transfers for disk and networking..    Best you can hope for is 400MB/s that thats open to contention from all the processes requested IO from the kernel.

Its simply not realistic to expect a RPI4 to operate at the same speed as a full fledged PC.

Comment: Can you post what method you are using to test the upload and download speed.

Comment: You can find tests (generally idealized as opposed to "real world") of the Pi4 getting about full (1000 Mbps) ethernet transfer speed.   Previous models with gigabit jacks did not come close due to other hardware bottlenecks (eg. shared bus with the USB).  You could try such a test to see the difference, which would be a start on narrowing down the cause. @SimonBanks *"the CPU is the ultimate bottleneck for IO transfers for disk and networking"* -> **This is so extremely false I am very tempted to call it by a less polite name.**

Comment: I'll try to respond to everyone:

I used `speedtest.net` to test both download and upload speed o both my desktop PC and the Pi4.

I'd be really fine with 400Mbps I just don't understand why my Pi4 never exceeds 100--140 ^^

Which tests would you advise me to do? I tried `iperf3 -s` but the shell stays silent indefinitely (I don't know why) so I could not get informations out of that for now.

Comment: I bet 100Mbps is plenty for internet browsing and watching Netfix.

Comment: well I thought too but it would seem it's not: everything is laggy… actually, I just need something like 4 or 5 chromium tabs and a youtube vidéo to make the four cores really busy! @Milliways I'd love to give better insights but I'm new to the PI so I'm still trying to understand